Reference request: axiomatizing Hamiltonian mechanics in infinitary logic
In the Wikipedia article on Quantum Logic, there is a section titled, "Logic of classical mechanics." If I am reading it right, that section says that the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics can be expressed in the infinitary language $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$, which is an extension of first-order logic that allows countable conjunctions and disjunctions. Unfortunately, this section of the Wikipedia article contains no references. I am familiar with $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$, but not familiar with Hamiltonian mechanics. I would like a reference to this fact which I can cite, and which hopefully elaborates on the details. Does anyone know of such a reference?
